# nestedscrollview inside recyclerview taking t much time to display data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

i created a custom calender using recycleview inside another recyclerview.
it working fine scroll is not smoothing so i search in stackoverflow changed to above code now scrolling smooth but if open that activity it taking tomuch time to display data i tested i will take 15 seconds to display data

Comment: Where is data coming from? Maybe the data source is slow.

Comment: data coming from arraylist(iam saving 5 years of dates hardcode in arraylist)

Comment: Please also post that code and the adapter code. Loading that much hardocded data at once might negatively affect performance.